# How to convert TTF to FNT with Fontforge

Tags: fonts, bitmap-fonts, fontforge

I have a TTF font, that needs to be converted in FNT (and ideally in pcf too). I tried Fontforge, but when I loaded font and chose to generate font - nothing could be selected from the list on the right, except "No bitmap fonts" though there was WIN FNT. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

FNT is a bitmap format while TTF is an outline/vector format. To get FNT output, you'll first need to create a bitmap strike or strikes. Fontforge can do this if it has been built with Freetype included:

- Go to Element -> Bitmap Strikes Available.
- Select the 'Win' button
- Under 'Point Sizes' enter the size (or sizes) you want.
- Tick 'Use FreeType' and 'Create Rasterized Strikes' Click OK.

You should now have a bitmap strike to work with. Go to Generate Fonts; on the left side select 'No Outline Font', and on the right side select Windows FNT, pick the size you want, and generate.

Answer (score 23):

**I recommend trying [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero). It can convert any installed system font or font file into `.fnt`.**

[You can download it from BadLogicGames.](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html)

- Open [**runnable-hiero.jar**](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/runnables/runnable-hiero.jar)
- Select the font you want to convert.

  - *For installed fonts on your PC*: Select **System**
  - *For downloaded font files*: Select **File** and choose a font by clicking **<kbd>...</kbd>**
- In the menubar, select **File → Save BMFont files (text)**
- Choose a save location and filename ending in `.fnt`

If done correctly, you should have two files for `font_name.fnt` and `font_name.png`

[image: Hiero v3.1 - Bitmap Font Tool]

Comment: Hi, I am using Mac. I run jar file using "java -jar fileName" . and this is what I got https://imgur.com/a/6g0nKYw .  . I can't find out how to convert it . I have loaded the hindi fonts.

Comment: @NeerPatel Just run the jar file by itself. You don’t need to add any parameters

Comment: what I am trying to say is that, after selecting the file, I can't find out any such clickable button as "convert" , which can convert .ttf file to .fnt file. please, have look at screenshot, you can see that I have selected the Mukta font. But now, How do I instruct the software to convert that file ?

Comment: @NeerPatel, Choose: File->Save BMFont files. If you want to change color then use Rendering: Java

Answer (score 15):

I built this online tool to convert **TrueType** fonts (.ttf) to **Bitmap** (.fnt)

https://ttf2fnt.com

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for anything I've tried uploading

Comment: It working perfectly on my Node project with Jimp. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any way to use any other characters than ascii? I was considering to use this tool with a-frame because it's really hard to find a bitmap font that support any other characters.

Comment: @milos Nice but how do we get accent like é to work?